# Need an equivalent for a C# code in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm doing C# And now I want to learn about VB.Net, and I want the equivalent for this:

```
Hide();
using (login loginForm = new login())
{
    var result = loginForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=298d12f2-fb55-4f34-aaba-4c122cbeba77

Comment: @LamyaLam - what exactly have you attempted yourself in order to learn? I don't understand how you will solve your next problem if you want a direct code translation.

Answer (score 2):

```
Hide()
Using loginForm As New login()
    Dim result = loginForm.ShowDialog()
    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        Show()
    Else
        Close()
    End If
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you try yourself? Just look up each thing on MSDN ([Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx), [If statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx), ...) and look at the code examples in VB.

Anyway, here is the converted code:

```
Hide()

Using loginForm As New login()
    Dim result = loginForm.ShowDialog()
    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        Show()
    Else
        Close()
    End If
End Using
```